# In The Context In Which-> Any replacement?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

I have this sentence:

> "Many people's personal information on the internet has been stolen by hackers. In this context, we can build a better security software to combat the problem".

However I want to put the phrase "we can build a better security software to combat the problem" at the beginning of the quote:

I make myself a sentence:

> "We can build a better security software to combat the context in which many people's personal information on the internet has been stolen by hackers."

Eventually, I feel that my sentence sounds unnatural. Am I correct? If so, is there other ways?

Comment: As a learner: Your sentence doesn't sound correct to me. You're not combating the context I guess!

Comment: **A software** is not good English because **software** is an uncountable noun and uncountable nouns do not directly take indefinite articles. A more idiomatic way to say that would be **a piece of software** if you're talking about one particular program. **Security software** (with no indefinite article) is fine, but that would refer to programs that have to do with information security in general, not to a particular program.

Answer (score 1):

When reversing the sentences, and changing them into a single one, you can use a construction that doesn't include **the context in which**:

> We can build X to combat **the problem of** Y.

Rephrasing your actual sentences, they could become:

> We can build a better security software to combat **the problem of** many people's personal information on the internet being stolen by hackers.

Note that there are grammar issues with other parts of the sentence, but I'm not going to address them specifically as that would be more like proofreading.

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for your detailed feed back. Could I ask you about another situation? For example if a sentence is: "The U.S has a rich mixture of cultural diversity, and the Medical standards for practice are to be read in this context". As "has a rich mixture of cultural diversity" is not categorised as "a problem" in this case. Is there a good way if I want to start the sentence with "The Medical standards for practice are to be read ..."? Thank you!

Comment: @PandoraU.U.D Try: *Medical standards for practice apply to the U.S.'s rich mixture of cultural diversity.*